# Get Dash instance when creating GNOME Shell Extension

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I'm creating my own extension for GNOME Shell and I run into problem while searching for some documentation of Dash.

I need to find `width`, `height`, `visibility` and `position` of Dash. But I have been unsuccesful to find some doc at https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/ about Dash at all. Is there any other page, where to find these information? How to get "instance" (object with these properties) of Dash?

EDIT:

I have found that method `Main.layoutManager.getWorkAreaForMonitor(0)` is the one that solve my problem. It does not returns instance of Dash as I was asking for (because of that I let answer opened), but it returns work-area of screen (work area is Rectangle of monitor size, without Panel and Dash). Access `x` and `y` for get left-top corner, `width` and `height` for size without Panel and Dash. When Dash is hidding when covered by window, work-area does not take Dash in count. Btw. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The dash is an internal part of GNOME Shell, and those are generally not documented. It's possible to manipulate it as many extensions do, but it's best to read the source code of the version of GNOME Shell that your extension is targeting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was long fight but I have been able to figure it out. Method I was looking for was `Main.layoutManager.getWorkAreaForMonitor(0)`. I was asking for something littlebit different (due lack of knowledge about GNOME Shell extensions), but this method is one that fullfil all my needs.